# Customize/modify PrimeVue Bootstrap theme SCSS/SASS

Tags: vue.js, sass, primevue

I'm new to PrimeVue and I'm trying to customize/modify the Bootstrap theme. I have a separate project where I completely modified the variables of Bootstrap (v4) and I want to use it in PrimeVue. I want to use SCSS so I can manage the styles well (just import the SCSS file needed in the component). How do I do that? Upon looking at the PrimeVue resources directory, it looks like it doesnt have the scss folder of Bootstrap, and it only shows the css file (generated). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I want to completely modify the variables instead of overriding the PrimeVue Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SASS API](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue-sass-theme) is open source now, available at github.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll check this out again in the future. But we ended up using React with MUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but you can only make changes in SASS variables if you buy the designer license from Primefaces - otherwise you'll get access only to prebuilt files.

See [the designer documentation here](https://www.primefaces.org/designer-vue/#/documentation).

Comment: Let's say I buy the license and download the scss files. in theory if I shared those files could anyone create primevue themes?